# Argument "nm" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

I have this function to create a dataset which includes all my prediction I have made before:

```
tst=setNames(
  data.frame(
    expand.grid(unique(df_sum[,"id"]),unique(df_sum[,"training"]),seq(25,100,25))
  )
)
```

Unfortunately, this message comes:

> Error in setNames(data.frame(expand.grid(unique(df_sum[, "id"]),
> unique(df_sum[,  :    argument "nm" is missing, with no default

It is a big dataset, so, it is hard to share. I hope you have enough details to help me.
Thanks

Comment: You are assiging your `data.frame` as `object` argument of `setNames` function.  You still need to provide `nm` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `help("setNames")` you will find under the heading "Usage" that `setNames` takes two arguments, called `object` and `nm`. The latter is missing in your call.

If your dataset is to large to share, please use a tiny part of it or some simulated data to publish small reproducible examples of what you try to do. We all have the `iris` dataset and a reproducible example for your problem might be as simple as

```
> setNames(iris)
Error in setNames(iris) : argument "nm" is missing, with no default
```

The answer is then

```
head( setNames(iris, nm = c("name1", "name2", "name3")) )
```